# MySQL C++ connector MySQL_Prepared_Statement::getUpdateCount error

Tags: c++, mysql-connector

I'm using MySQL C++ connector version 1.1.0.
This is how my code looks like:

```
PreparedStatement *pStatement;
connection->setAutoCommit(false);

pStatement = connection->prepareStatement("UPDATE records "
            "SET is_processed = ? "
            "WHERE id = ?");

    //LOOP BEGIN
    pStatement->setInt(1, is_processed);
    pStatement->setString(2, record_id);

    pStatement->execute();
    //LOOP END

int updated_records;

try 
{
    updated_records = pStatement->getUpdateCount();
}
catch(SQLException&e)
{
    cout << "ERROR: " << e.what();
    cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
    cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << ")" << endl;
}

connection->commit();
connection->setAutoCommit(true);
```

The exception is thrown with following output:

```
ERROR: MySQL_Prepared_Statement::getUpdateCount (MySQL error code: 0, SQLState: )
```

So it says totally nothing. What's wrong with `getUpdateCount()` function? Is there some way I can get more detailed error reporting level?

**EDIT**

Is there any other way to get updated rows count using mysql c++ connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found working solution:

```
int updated_records = 0;

    //LOOP BEGIN
    pStatement->setInt(1, is_processed);
    pStatement->setString(2, record_id);

    updated_records += pStatement->executeUpdate();
    //LOOP END

cout << updated_records;
```

`executeUpdate()` return number of affected rows and it works without any error, so that's enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem as well. I ended up taking a look at the source code. It appears that the source explicitly will throw an exception.

```
uint64_t
MySQL_Prepared_Statement::getUpdateCount()
{
  checkClosed();
  throw MethodNotImplementedException("MySQL_Prepared_Statement::getUpdateCount");
  return 0; // fool compilers
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To clarify for others, because I was confused; do it like this:

```
pstmt = con->prepareStatement ("UPDATE localdata SET Val = ? WHERE ID = ?");
pstmt->setDouble (1, 7.77);    // first "?"
pstmt->setInt (2, 0);    // second "?"
pstmt->executeUpdate ();
```

The trick is setting the values according to their table type and order in the statement.